# MarkLogic - xdmp:document-filter() gives ISYS-FAILED error

Tags: marklogic

Our code applies document-filter on incoming zips and PDFs. So, we have this zip that is composed of **3 *.sdf.gz** files.
It fails to convert the zip into xhtml and gives this error :

> ISYS-FAILED: xdmp:document-filter(document{binary{"504b03040a00000000005da89550000000000000000000000000080000006372..."}}) -- Document-Filter failed due to **abnormal process termination: -1. terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ISYS_NS::ECharacterConversion'\n  what():  lpOutput cannot be nullptr .** See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.

So, I tried to pass individual *.sdf.gz file to `xdmp:document-filter()`, it failed with same error as above for 2 out of 3 files.

Does anyone have any idea how do we resolve this OR if this is the expected behavior for certain type of files?

If anyone has encountered similar problem and was able to find some helpful resource/solution for this please share here.

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with the content of those files, but it's hard to tell without seeing them and exploring. I just tested with a random sdf.gz file, and it didn't throw an error, but returned the HTML result with content-type, filter-capabilities, and size. You might want to open a MarkLogic Support case and provide the offending file and see what they can do.

Comment: Thanks @MadsHansen I did check with other zips and I don't get this problem. So, it might have to do with contents in that specific zip.